# How to call an IBAction based on the output of an integer variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Suppose i have 5 IBAction Methods

```
-(IBAction)tappedBlock1:(id)sender
{
           self.block1.image = self.oImg;
}
-(IBAction)tappedBlock2:(id)sender
{
       self.block2.image = self.oImg;
}
-(IBAction)tappedBlock3:(id)sender
{
           self.block3.image = self.oImg;
}
-(IBAction)tappedBlock4:(id)sender
{
       self.block4.image = self.oImg;
}
-(IBAction)tappedBlock5:(id)sender
{
        self.block5.image = self.oImg;
}
```

And another function that generates a random number from 1 - 5.
Now based on the random number i want to call the action.
I am using if-else statements to perform this action but it increases the size of my code a lot.
Heres the code

```
-(void)generateRandom
{
    NSInteger random;
reCheckrandom:random = arc4random()%5;
    if(random == 0)
    {
        [self tappedBlock1:self];
    }
    if(random == 1)
    {
        [self tappedBlock2:self];
    }
    if(random == 2)
    {
        [self tappedBlock3:self];
    }
    if(random == 3)
    {
        [self tappedBlock4:self];
    }
    if(random == 4)
    {
        [self tappedBlock5:self];
    }


}
```

Is there any better way to perform the same action??

Comment: In generateRandom give tags for buttons and only one IBAction there  use switch case and give action according to tags..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `NSSelectorFromString` that generates selector form the string, like :

```
-(void)generateRandom
{
    NSInteger random;
    random = arc4random()%5;

    NSString *method = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tappedBlock%d",random];
    SEL s = NSSelectorFromString(method);
    [self performSelector:s withObject:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically generate the selector's name:

```
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"tappedBlock%ld",(long)random]);

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [self performSelector:selector withObject:self];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

The #pragmas silence the annoying warning about memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

By looking in yours code, I think you need just one function:

```
-(void)generateRandom
{
    [self.blocks[arc4random()%self.blocks.count] setImage:self.oImg];
}
```

where `self.blocks` is `NSArray` of yours blocks.